# get the from_date and to_date in total number of day php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, time

```html
$from_date = $this->input->post('from_date);12/3/2016
$to_date = $this->input->post('to_date);14/3/2016
```

i want the answer like 12,13,14 total 3 days i need
how to get the result like that.
i tried diff,interval in php i got only difference that's it.
anybody please help
 $diff = $date1->date_diff($date2); give 2 days i don't need difference
i need total days including from_date to to_date

Comment: You can add one day to the result. This answer will be always correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using Datetime :

```
$from = new DateTime($from_date, new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));
$to = new DateTime($to_date, new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));

$interval = $from->diff($to);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $start_date =  new DateTime("12-3-2016");
    $end_date =  new DateTime("14-3-2016");
    $total_days = $end_date->diff($start_date)->days +1 ;
    while($start_date <= $end_date) {
        echo $start_date->format("d")."<br>";
        $start_date = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($start_date->format("d-m-Y")))));
    }
    echo "Total days : ".$total_days;

?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/537957

Comment: i think about that, that's not fair solution,  is there any function like count() , to the total number of days from_date to to_date

Comment: You can use date diff method.

Comment: $total_days = $start_date->diff($end_date) + 1;

Comment: @Rakesh : Updated my ans

Answer (score 0):

simple I made it easy.
$to->modify('+1 days');
php function and works great